# Animation doesn't work when orientation of activity is set to land

Tags: android, android-animation

When I set orientation of my activity to landscape:

```
android:screenOrientation="landscape"
```

in AndroidManifest.xml file, It doesn't play 
the animation that is set with:

```
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.activity_in, R.anim.activity_out);
```

What should I do in this situation to start this activity with animation?

Comment: Post your animations .xml file.

Comment: Animation works fine after removing line `android:screenOrientation="landscape"`.